# Integrating WordPress features into an Ionic 4 web application

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, wordpress-rest-api

I am building Web application with a new Ionic 4 Framework and multiple WordPress installations (in subdomains on same server).

I want to use WordPress installations from my subdomain (ie: stream.example.com, download.example.com, site.example.com ) to use certain features from WordPress like display user avatar, and user name when logged in, or check if user is logged in and display membership content and if user is logged out display alternative content.

I would like to use the WordPress API to use certain features and display or NOT display certain content or options to users. I am new to using ionic 4 framework coming from bootstrap it seems pretty simple. But I am not familiar with using any API yet alone the complex WordPress. Here is the main user interface coding; you can also check it out live at https://www.cynclabs.com

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"></script>
        <script nomodule src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/css/ionic.bundle.css"/>
        <script src="https://cynclabs.com/js/stickyaudioplayerjquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cynclabs.com/css/stickyaudioplayerjquery.min.css">
       <title>Cync Labs Official </title>
    </head>

    <body> 
    <ion-app> <---// Will like the option to show this content to only logged in users//--->
      <ion-menu side="start" menu-id="first">
        <ion-header>
          <ion-toolbar class="cync-toolbar">
            <ion-title>Start Menu</ion-title>
          </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>
        <ion-content>


        <ion-card>
            <ion-avatar>
 <---// the following image will be the registered users wordpress avatar// --->
              <img src="https://gravatar.com/avatar/dba6bae8c566f9d4041fb9cd9ada7741?d=identicon&f=y">
            </ion-avatar>
          <ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-subtitle>Welcome Back</ion-card-subtitle>
            <ion-card-title>Wordpress User Name Will GO Here</ion-card-title>
          </ion-card-header>

          <ion-card-content>
            Wordpress Membership TItle Will be Here (Displayer specific user membership tier), This Link WIll Go Here for the option to upgrade
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>

      <ion-list>
        <ion-item> menu one</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>

  <ion-menu side="start" menu-id="custom" class="my-custom-menu">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar class="cync-toolbar">
        <ion-title>Custom Menu</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>

  <ion-menu side="end" type="push">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar class="cync-toolbar">
        <ion-title>End Menu</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>

  <div class="ion-page" main>
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar class="cync-toolbar">
        <ion-title>
            <ion-row>
            <ion-col size="4">
              <div>
                <ion-button expand="block" onclick="openFirst()">Open Start Menu</ion-button>
              </div>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col size="4">
              <div>
                <center><ion-img width="80" height="80" onclick="openEnd()" src="https://cynclabs.com/images/logo.png"></ion-img></center>
              </div>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col size="4">
              <div>
                <ion-button expand="block" onclick="openCustom()">Open Custom Menu</ion-button>
              </div>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>  
        </ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content class="ion-padding" >



      <div id="contentarea">
<---//would like to php load the wordpress page content from the menus in here using ajax/jquery//--->(No IFrame)
</div>

    </ion-content>
  </div>

</ion-app>
<ion-menu-controller></ion-menu-controller>

  <style>.my-custom-menu {
            --width: 80px;
            }
        </style>

        <!!-- this menu animation -- > 
        <script>
             const menuCtrl = document.querySelector('ion-menu-controller');

                function openFirst() {
                  menuCtrl.enable(true, 'first');
                  menuCtrl.open('first');
                }

                function openEnd() {
                  menuCtrl.open('end');
                }

                function openCustom() {
                  menuCtrl.enable(true, 'custom');
                  menuCtrl.open('custom');
                }
         </script>

         <style>

    .cync-toolbar{
    --background: rgba(76,185,196,1);
    --background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(76,185,196,1) 0%, rgba(61,211,174,1) 100%);
    --background: -webkit-gradient(left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(76,185,196,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(61,211,174,1)));
    --background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(76,185,196,1) 0%, rgba(61,211,174,1) 100%);
    --background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(76,185,196,1) 0%, rgba(61,211,174,1) 100%);
    --background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(76,185,196,1) 0%, rgba(61,211,174,1) 100%);
    --background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(76,185,196,1) 0%, rgba(61,211,174,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4cb9c4', endColorstr='#3dd3ae', GradientType=1 );

    --color:#ffffff;
}

.devBox-content{
     background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #051937, #004d7a, #008793, #00bf72, #a8eb12) !important;
}
</style>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a five part tutorial series called **Build a PWA with Ionic, Angular, and the WordPress REST API** which might be helpful to this goal:

### [Part 1](https://codyburleson.com/pwa-with-ionic-angular-wordpress-api-1/), [Part 2](https://codyburleson.com/pwa-with-ionic-angular-wordpress-api-2/), [Part 3](https://codyburleson.com/pwa-with-ionic-angular-wordpress-api-3/), [Part 4](https://codyburleson.com/pwa-with-ionic-angular-wordpress-api-4/), [Part 5](https://codyburleson.com/pwa-with-ionic-angular-wordpress-api-5/)